# I don't know how can I write l ∈ {i, j} the below conditions in CPLEX?

Tags: cplex

**y[ijk]≤q[lk] ,(i,j,k) ∈ A_3  , l ∈ {i, j},**

Is that correct??
forall(<i,j,k> in A3, **l in node :i!=j** )
y[<i,j,k>]<=q[l][k];

My problem is l ∈ {i, j} I don't know how to write on cplex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use || (or)

```
forall(<i,j,k> in A3, l in node :(i!=j) && ((l==i)||(l==j)) ) y[<i,j,k>]<=q[l][k];
```